# my mask is not the right size

Tags: masking

[image: four]

the mask is too small but in the movie clip editor its looks good
is it because I filmed with an iPhone

I can resize it my self but I want it to be normal

Comment: The brand of the camera phone is not relevant to the question. You are rendering at 50%, which will make the image half the size. Bring up the resolution to 100% or add a distort>scale node and set it to "Render Size".

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81208/how-to-make-overlayed-composited-images-stay-intact-while-changing-render-resolu